# R (counting unique occurrences)

Tags: r, grouping

I'm new to R and looking to do the following.

I have data in file 1 like -

```
Cookie  Bannerid
b   1
c   2
d   3
e   4
b   2
c   3
f   Blank
g   Blank
h       5
```

data in File 2 maps these bannerid to bannersize (something like) -

```
BannerID    BannerSize
1           300X250
2           728X90
3           728X90
4           300X250
5               300X250
```

The output I want is like

```
Banner Size       No. of cookies that show up only in that banner size
300X250           1
728X90            1
```

Comment: How is it `1` for `728X90`? could you explain?

Comment: Hi Arun, D only present in bannerid=3 which maps to 728X90.

Comment: @AhmerK, then for `300X250` it must be 2 = `e` and `h`..?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not quite sure I understand this. However, this is an attempt using `data.table`.

```
require(data.table)
# assuming your data.frames are df1 and df2
dt1 <- data.table(df1)
dt2 <- data.table(df2, key="BannerID")
dt3 <- dt1[, N := .N, by="Cookies"][N == 1]
setkey(dt3, "Bannerid")
o <- na.omit(dt3[dt2])

> o
#    Bannerid Cookie BannerSize
# 1:        3      d     728X90
# 2:        4      e    300X250
# 3:        5      h    300X250

o[, .N, by=BannerSize]

#    BannerSize N
# 1:     728X90 1
# 2:    300X250 2
```

Is this what you're expecting??

Comment: Yes, Arun, It must be 2 for 300X250. My bad. missed that while typing the example. The actual file I'll be using this on has around 200k cookies so wrote this example in haste.